# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when tring to map through the api data

Tags: react-hooks, axios

**I'm trying to pass array data from the backend and display the said data as a set of divs but the map() function says undefined???**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Chats = () => {
  const { chat, setChat } = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await axios
        .get("/api/chats")
        .then((response) => {
          setChat(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
      setChat(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [setChat]);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {chat.map((d) => (
          <div key={d}>{d.chatName}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chats;
```

api data sent >>>

```
{"isGroupChat":true,"users":[{"name":"John Doe","email":"jon@example.com"},{"name":"Piyush","email":"piyush@example.com"},{"name":"Guest User","email":"guest@example.com"}],"_id":"617a518c4081150716472c78","chatName":"Friends","groupAdmin":{"name":"Guest User","email":"guest@example.com"}}
```

**Eror on the console >>>**
*Line 12:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Chats
```

I have tried adding react-hook as a plugin as `"plugins": ["react", "react-hooks",],` so with no progress. Why does it keep saying "nnot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
"?
Help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Effects always run after rendering, so it is possible for fetchData to be undefined because it hasn't run yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effects run after a render, so it is possible for your API data to be undefined. A common practice in React is to make sure you have your data back first before rendering something. You can check to see what should be returned based on if your data is undefined or not; in this case your API data

```
return (
  <>
   {typeof chat !== 'undefined' ?
     <div>
       {chat.map((d) => (
          <div key={d}>{d.chatName}</div>
       ))}
     </div>
  : <div>Loading...</div>
  }
</>
);
```

You can have a loading state here in a various ways until the data returns, but I would probably call a function and pass the data to this component rather than utilizing useEffect this way due to performance. This would be an example of when to pass in data layer values from another function so that you can know if the values are defined or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
      <div>
        {chat?.map((d) => (
          <div key={d}>{d.chatName}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
 );
```